# How can I add product to cart programmatically using username and product sku in Magento?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.5

I have the username and the product SKU, the user is not logged into Magento. My aim is to add this product to the user's cart. And then using the username, I need to get all the products in the user's cart. So, how can I do this from the outside of the Magento? That means, my php file will not be inside any of the Magento directories (if it makes any difference).